# WSE client project keeps reverting WebServicesClientProtocol to SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, vista64, wse, wse3.0

Despite enabling WSE 3.0 on client projects in Visual Studio 2005, web references I make always end up with service proxies derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol. I have to manually change the inheritance to WebServicesClientProtocol, but updating it will revert back to SoapHttpClientProtocol. I am unsure where in Visual Studio project properties can I get it to permanently use WebServicesClientProtocol?

---

As far as I have read, Visual Studio is supposed to generate the regular SoapHttpClientProtocol-based service proxy, plus another service proxy suffixed with the "Wse" name that derives from Web ServicesClientProtocol. [Even Visual Studio .NET 2003 already had this feature](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/VSNET-2003-Auto-Generates-WSE-Proxies-2b-WSE-Settings-Tool.aspx). So for some reason my Visual Studio 2005 is not tightly cooperating with WSE 3.0 to generate the additional WebServicesClientProtocol proxy. But where is the missing link?

---

Update 13 Jan 09

I got another machine to test this, and behold this Visual Studio 2005 *can* generate proxies based on WebServicesClientProtocol. That means my original workstation's Visual Studio has been messed up; not too sure how one can repair this though.

Add: Mmmm, reinstalling WSE 3.0 did not help either. Maybe WSE just does not work on a x64 Windows Vista... ?

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Comment: WSE is "not obsolete" when studying for certification :-/

Comment: Many organizations don't permit such obsolete software to be used in production. To them, it's quite relevant.

Comment: Not obsolete when you have applications which can't be upgraded beyond .NET 2.0

Comment: With all of the "WSE is obsolete" messages that are plastered everywhere someone asks this sort of question, I have yet to see a good transition guide for someone who is looking to migrate client functionality from WSE to WCF. I have tried, with varying levels of success (failure) to get the simplest things working, but have not reaped a great reward for my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like being a [64-bit operating system certainly has its demerits](http://icelava.net/forums/thread/5224.aspx).

The WSE 3.0 installer fails to alter Visual Studio 2005's config file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config with the following entry.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionImporterTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Description.WseExtensionImporter,
           Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </soapExtensionImporterTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you are awesome icelava. while my specific issue was somewhat more pedestrian, your contributions helped me greatly! thanks!